# If every Left Cosets of H are Right Cosets of H, show that H is normal in G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

If H is a subgroup of a group G and if every Left Cosets of H are Right Cosets of H, show that H is normal in G

As per the question, consider a left coset $aH$ and a right coset $Hb$ such that $aH=Hb$, $a,b\in G $ and $a\neq b$.

If $a=b$ then H is normal in G, by the definition of normal subgroup.

My question is if $aH=Hb$ then does it imply $a=b$ always? Please answer

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: To show H is normal in G

Comment: What definition of *normal* are you using?

Comment: a subgroup H of a group G is normal in G if and only if gH = Hg for all g in G

Comment: So you have to show that if $aH=Hb$ then $Ha=Hb$.

Comment: how to show this